# 親要素に角丸ボーダーを付けると中の要素の角が目立つ

Tags: html, css

下記のコードですが、親要素に角丸ボーダーをつけると中の要素の角が目立ちます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px; 
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 8px;
    ">
        <div style="
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        ">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

子要素にも同様の `border-radius: 8px;` をつけると添付画像のようになりうまくいきません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この状態で、さらに親要素に

`background-color: red;` を足すと、それっぽくなりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

角はいい感じになりましたが、
背景色がすべてRedになったので、今まで白い領域もなくなってしまいました。

なにかよい解決策はありませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

（なぜか急に検索がうまくいき、下記の記事にたどりつきました。）

[CSS：border-radiusで子要素の角が丸くならない問題 | ゆずどっとこむ](https://yu-z.com/border-radius/)

> overflow: hidden;を書いてあげましょう。
> 実際は、.box（親要素）は角丸になっているものの、子要素が角丸になっていないだけです。
> 角丸の形に切り抜いてあげましょう。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px; 
        border-style: solid;
        border-radius: 8px;
        overflow: hidden;
    ">
        <div style="
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        ">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```